# Best way to connect java swing app to ms access db on a shareserver?

Tags: java, swing, ms-access

Currently im developing a java swing application that I'd like to serve as the GUI for CRUD operations on a MS access database. Currently, everyone on the team that will be using this application updates a spreadsheet on a shareserver. They'd like to switch over to a UI that better suits their purposes, and transition the spreadsheet to a database.

I'm planning on putting an executable jar and the ms access database file on the shareserver. This is where the jar will be accessed.

I don't want users to have to be messing with ODBC settings. Is there a library that can help with this?

UPDATE: Shailendrasingh Patil's suggestion below worked best for me. This took me a little bit of research and the setup was a bit confusing. But I eventually got everything working the way I was hoping. I used Gradle to pull in the necessary dependencies to use UcanAccess.

The following is a snippet from my DatabaseController class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class DatabaseController {

    public DatabaseController() {}

    public void addOperation(String date, String email, String subject, String body) {
    try{
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\TestDatabase.accdb;jackcessOpener=CryptCodecOpener","user", "password");

        String sql = "INSERT INTO Email (Date_Received, Email_Address, Subject, Message) Values " +
                "('"+date+"'," +
                "'"+email+"'," +
                "'"+subject+"'," +
                "'"+body+"')";

        Statement statement = con.createStatement();
        statement.execute(sql);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage(),"Error",
                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

The following class is also required:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.CryptCodecProvider;
import com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.Database;
import com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.DatabaseBuilder;
import net.ucanaccess.jdbc.JackcessOpenerInterface;

public class CryptCodecOpener implements JackcessOpenerInterface {
public Database open(File fl,String pwd) throws IOException {
    DatabaseBuilder dbd =new DatabaseBuilder(fl);
    dbd.setAutoSync(false);
    dbd.setCodecProvider(new CryptCodecProvider(pwd));
    dbd.setReadOnly(false);
    return dbd.open();
}
}
```

I apologize for the bad indentations.

Comment: I would suggest you use a real database (not a ms access one). SQL Server, or MySQL (or Postgres). Failing that, I would prefer SQLite.

Comment: Also avoid thinking about connecting a gui library with a database. The two sections of code, the one dealing with the GUI and the other dealing with database access should be kept entirely separate and should preferably be completely agnostic of each other. This way you can use the same GUI code for any persistence framework that you desire, and visa versa -- you could use any GUI library with your database code. Of course you'd need bridging code, but strive for code with low coupling and high cohesion.

Comment: Thanks for your input. In this scenario, I will be limited to using MS Access. Both the executable jar and access database file will be stored on a shareserver. The jar will not be stored on the users local machines. What I need to avoid is users having to go into control panel administrative settings to adjust odbc settings. Not all users have admin access on their machines.

Comment: You need to make this question much more specific. Asking for general recommendations or "best way..." is off topic for this site as it is geared towards answering much more specific questions. Please go through the [tour], the [help] and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: Last time I tried this years ago one could create Access ODBC entries on system _and_ user level, that means you don't need to be administrator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use UCanAccess drivers to connect to MS-Access. It is a pure JDBC based and you don't need ODBC drivers.
Refer examples [here](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html#examples)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. This worked for me. I updated my results in my question above!